# apache-libcloud create temporary url

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage, libcloud

I would like to generate a temporary download url using cloudlib.

I understand how to create the link by [manually contructing the url](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs), but I would like to use libcloud if possible so I can easily swap out google cloud storage.